# python os.path.join for a frozen exe

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on code that uses os.walk to search through a relative path.  When I run it as a python script I have no problems but after converting it to an exe it can't seem to find the relative path.  The current path prints fine  Below is the current solution that i have been working on.

> ```
> if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
>     currentPath = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
>     relativePath = os.path.join(currentPath,'/../../folder')
> else:
>     currentPath = inspect.stack()[0][1]
>     relativePath = os.path.join(currentPath,'/../../folder')
> ```
>
> `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(relativePath):`

When hardcoding the relativePath the exe works.

> relativePath = "D:/location/../../folder"

Is there something tricky with joining when converting to an exe that I'm missing?

Comment: What do you get when you print `currentPath`?

Comment: Are there mixed backslashes and forward slashes in your path names, due to sys.executable being something like "c:\program files\myprog\myprog.exe"? Try making your joins like os.path.join(currentPath, '..', '..', folder) I'm just WAGging here because I don't fully understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but the cause could be that you are mixing backslashes and forward slashes in the path.

Try changing the code that creates `relativePath` to the following:

```
relativePath = os.path.join(currentPath, '..', '..', 'folder')
```

This should ensure that you are definitely using the correct path separator.

Comment: Bingo! windows = \ i've been using / in python. Thanks FJ and Paul